# Reference on the general solution of heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We know

$$
K(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{4t})
$$

is a solution to the heat equation:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$

I would like to ask how to prove:

$$
u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x-y,t)f(y)dy
$$

is also the solution to the equation. And also:

$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+} u(x,t) = f(x)
$$

It seems [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions) is a well known result, however I would like to ask for some references on this on how this is proved.

Comment: [Olver](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/3223_2019-10-28-13-12-55.pdf) goes through the derivation in Chapter 8 I believe?

Comment: A very clear and rigorous explanation in Guenther & Lee.